# Finiteness of $H_1 \backslash G / H_2$ and the geometry of the orbits

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, spherical-varieties

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over an algebraically closed field $k$. By the Bruhat decomposition, $P \backslash G/P \cong W_P \backslash W / W_P$ is a finite set for any parabolic subgroup $P$ of $G$. So there is some connection between the combinatorics of the Weyl group and the geometry of the orbits.

Now consider two closed subgroups $H_i$ of $G$.

> When is $ H_1 \backslash G / H_2$ finite? In such cases, can we describe the $H_1$-orbits in $G/H_2$ using some group theoretic data or combinatoric data in general?

If $H_1$ is a Borel subgroup, the finiteness is equivalent to $G/H_2$ being a spherical variety. And things become trivial if $H_1=G$.

> If $H_1=H_2$, is the finiteness equivalent to $H_1=H_2$ being a parabolic subgroup? For low rank $G$, can we classify all such pair $(H_1,H_2)$?

Comment: Is there an example where non of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is parabolic?

Comment: @WilleLiou, try taking $H_1=H_2$ to be diagonal matrices in $G=GL_2$...

Comment: @paulgarrett I believe $T_2 \backslash GL_2 /T_2$ is not finite, as $a_{11}a_{22}/a_{12}a_{21}$ is invariant.

Comment: @sawdada you can also seeing this for dimension reasons, since scalar matrices act the same on both sides, so the quotient is 1-dim’l

Comment: Well, right, the point is that in the tiny group $GL_2$, where over an algebraically closed field we can easily identify all algebraic subgroups, we don't get finite double-coset spaces unless (at least) one of the subgroups is a (proper) parabolic. Yes, in this case, as in many, _dimension_ easily gives a _necessary_ condition for finiteness.

Comment: A good example is when $K=G^\theta$ is a fixed point set of some involution (then $G/K$ is called symmetric). The double coset space $K\backslash G/K$ has a good description and can be both finite or infinite. So $P$ doesn't have to be parabolic in general.

Comment: @VictorPetrov Thank you, can you give me a reference or a non-example?

Comment: @sawdada Sorry, seems that I was wrong and it is always infinite except the trivial case $K=G$.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer all your questions, but it seems relevant enough to post.

In *The orbits of affine symmetric spaces under the action of minimal parabolic subgroups* by T. Matsuki(1977), the double coset spaces $H\backslash G/P$ are described and shown to be **finite** where $G$ is a real semisimple Lie group, $P$ is a minimal parabolic, and $G^{\sigma}_0\subset H\subset G^\sigma$ where $G^{\sigma}$ denotes the closed subgroup of $G$ consisting of all the elements fixed by an involution $\sigma$.

When $H$ is the maximal compact, the quotient is trivial because of the Iwasawa decomposition.  When $H$ is a real form of a complex semisimple Lie group $G$, this is a result of Aomoto from 1965 (in that case $P=B$, the Borel). And in the case where $G$ is a product of a semisimple Lie group with itself and $H$ is the diagonal, then this reduces to the Bruhat decomposition you mention in your question.

Comment: Clickable link: [Matsuki - The orbits of affine symmetric spaces under the action of minimal parabolic subgroups](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1240319344) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=527548)).